# Shutdown problems

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, acpi

My laptop Packard Bell ENTG71BM does not want to shutdown with ubuntu 14.04. With Windows all OK. I used a lot of different advices(edit Grub, update BIOS), but it still does not work correctly. 
I`m almost sure, that trouble is in ACPI. I have logs:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007867a000-0x0000000078779fff] ACPI NVS

[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007877a000-0x00000000787b9fff] ACPI data

[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000794d0000-0x0000000079dcffff] ACPI NVS

[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled

[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000FE020 000024 (v02 ACRSYS)

[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000787B9120 00008C (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003      01000013)

[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000787B6000 0000F4 (v04 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000787A9000 0077FA (v02 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x0000000078742000 000040

[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000787B8000 000236 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000787B5000 000038 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: LPIT 0x00000000787B4000 000104 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000787B3000 000084 (v03 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000787B2000 00003C (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000003 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000787B1000 000763 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00003000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000787A7000 000290 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00003000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000787A6000 00017A (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00003000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000787A5000 000042 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000787A2000 002F10 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00001000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000787A1000 00013D (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00001000 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000787A0000 000044 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000002 1025 00040000)

[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000

[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408

[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x04] disabled)

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x06] disabled)

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high level lint[0x1])

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high level lint[0x1])

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high level lint[0x1])

[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high level lint[0x1])

[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x02] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])

[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)

[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)

[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.

[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.

[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information

[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000

[    0.000053] ACPI: Core revision 20141107

[    0.014130] ACPI: All ACPI Tables successfully acquired

[    0.107621] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7867a000-0x78779fff] (1048576 bytes)

[    0.107651] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x794d0000-0x79dcffff] (9437184 bytes)

[    0.116926] ACPI: bus type PCI registered

[    0.116930] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5

[    0.121631] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)

[    0.121637] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)

[    0.121639] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)

[    0.121642] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)

[    0.131423] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[    0.131438] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88017A5F0800 000440 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20130117)

[    0.132260] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[    0.132271] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88017A5F1000 000433 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20130117)

[    0.133488] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[    0.133499] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88017A5A5600 00015F (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20130117)

[    0.134289] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:

[    0.134299] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88017A5AD900 00008D (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20130117)

[    0.136345] ACPI: Interpreter enabled

[    0.136359] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20141107/hwxface-580)

[    0.136368] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20141107/hwxface-580)

[    0.136395] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)

[    0.136399] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing

[    0.136459] PCI: Ignoring host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=use_crs" and report a bug

[    0.546523] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)

[    0.551193] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)

[    0.551475] ACPI: Power Resource [PLPE] (on)

[    0.552379] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)

[    0.553399] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])

[    0.553410] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]

[    0.554212] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PME]

[    0.554561] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug AER PCIeCapability]

[    0.555004] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [io  0x0000-0x006f] (ignored)

[    0.555009] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [io  0x0078-0x0cf7] (ignored)

[    0.555013] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff] (ignored)

[    0.555017] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff] (ignored)

[    0.555021] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff] (ignored)

[    0.555024] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff] (ignored)

[    0.555028] acpi PNP0A08:00: host bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0x909ffffe] (ignored)

[    0.555037] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge

[    0.556158] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.556912] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.557120] pci 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.557333] pci 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.557670] pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.558772] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.565180] pci 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

[    0.777263] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7

[    0.777382] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)

[    0.777498] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)

[    0.777623] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)

[    0.777738] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)

[    0.777853] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7

[    0.777970] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)

[    0.778086] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7

[    0.778631] ACPI: Enabled 4 GPEs in block 00 to 3F

[    0.778822] ACPI : EC: GPE = 0x18, I/O: command/status = 0x66, data = 0x62

[    0.779650] ACPI: bus type USB registered

[    0.780028] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing

[    0.792560] pnp: PnP ACPI init

[    0.792656] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)

[    0.792829] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)

[    0.793023] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)

[    0.793141] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD050a SYN1b00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)

[    0.996895] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)

[    0.997242] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices

[    1.005505] Switched to clocksource acpi_pm

[    3.314196] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (on-line)

[    3.314429] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]

[    3.314512] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]

[    3.314627] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]

[    3.314709] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]

[    3.317776] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (49 C)

[    3.318931] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)

[    3.379548] ACPI PCC probe failed.

[    3.657500] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)

[   13.077676] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras

[   13.100607] acer_wmi: Brightness must be controlled by acpi video driver
```

Can anyone say that everything was in order?
Do i really have problems with ACPI?